# VBScript Erroring on getelementbyid for an element that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript

I have this block of code and when i = 9 it errors.  The object T_009 does not exist in the html form, but I don't understand why it would cause it to error out, isn't that what the not is nothing checks for?  I have several forms that use vbscript and don't have the time to convert them all so I'm stuck with what it is...

```
dim i, obj_src, obj_dest
for i = 2 to 720
    set obj_src = document.getelementbyid("T_" & lpad(i,"0",3))
    set obj_dest = document.getelementbyid("s" & lpad(i,"0",3))
    if not obj_src is nothing and not obj_dest is nothing then
        obj_dest.innerhtml = obj_src.value
    end if
    set obj_src = nothing
    set obj_dest = nothing
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to enable compatibility mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```